# Redirect to file directory non existent

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I'm calling this command in Python:

```
os.system('echo %s  > `find $HOME -iname p410.yaml`' % string)
```

This works fine on OSX, but on Ubuntu gives me `/home/path/to/p410.yaml: Directory nonexistent`. I can however edit the file at the path it gives me with vim.

Any idea whats up?

#### EDIT

Output from stat `find $HOME -iname p410.yaml`

```
File: `/home/aslab/chris_ws/src/pulseon_p400/config/p410.yaml'
  Size: 124         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 460669      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/   aslab)   Gid: ( 1001/   aslab)
Access: 2014-12-22 13:45:57.000000000 +1000
Modify: 2014-12-22 13:44:45.000000000 +1000
Change: 2014-12-22 13:44:45.000000000 +1000
 Birth: -
  File: `/home/aslab/uwb_ws/src/pulseon_p400/launch/p410.yaml'
  Size: 163         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 457183      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1001/   aslab)   Gid: ( 1001/   aslab)
Access: 2014-12-19 08:11:30.000000000 +1000
Modify: 2014-09-12 14:37:19.000000000 +1000
Change: 2014-09-12 14:37:19.000000000 +1000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Comment: that was just an attempt to get it working, its irrelevant really. ill remove that to avoid confusion

Comment: What happens if you run `find $HOME -iname p410.yaml` directly in the shell?

Comment: it returns me the path to it. it lets me go vim `find ... p410.yam` fine

Comment: What if you run `stat \`find $HOME -iname p410.yaml\``?

Comment: Does this occur if you isolate that line of Python code and run it all by itself?

Comment: figured it out - two files with same name. why the interpreter wouldn't give me that I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that there were two files with the same name, which through the error messages that filtered through the Python interpreter was a bit obscured. To be honest I'm also surprised that when I called `vim 'find $HOME -iname p410.yaml'` it worked when there were two options of which file to open.

Comment: No surprise, `vim onefile another` will just edit both files one at a time (`:n` moves you to the second one when you're done with the first).